# Write file to directory based on variable in Python

Tags: python, filesystems

The script will generate multiple files using the `year` and `id` variable. These files need to be placed into a folder matching `year` and `id`. How do I write them to the correct folders?

```
file_root_name = row["file_root_name"]
year = row["year"]
id = row["id"]
path = year+'-'+id
try:
    os.makedirs(path)
except:
    pass
output = open(row['file_root_name']+'.smil', 'w')
output.write(prettify(doctype, root))
```

Comment: Are you asking how to put directory and file name together using `os.path.join`?  Is that what you're struggling with?

Comment: The script will generate multiple files using the `year` and `id` variable. These files need to be placed into a folder matching `year` and `id`.

Comment: That's what the question says.  Folder names and file names are combined with `os.path.join`.  Are you asking how to use `os.path.join`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to do this:

```
import os.path
file_name = row['file_root_name']+'.smil'
full_path = os.path.join(path, file_name)
output = open(full_path, 'w')
```

Please note that it's not very common in Python to use the + operator for string concatenation. Although not in your case, with large strings the method is not very fast.
I'd prefer:

```
file_name = '%s.smil' % row['file_root_name']
```

and:

```
path = '%i-%i' % (year, id)
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'm just beginning and learning by example.

Comment: with your methon I get `TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str`

Comment: @DavidNeudorfer: Why is the year or id a string?  They're usually numbers.  If %i or %d don't work, you have  a string, and must use %s.

Comment: @S.Lott: from a previous question I know that his year and id are coming from a csv.DictReader row, and are left as they're found, hence the strings.

Comment: @S.Lott I pulled `year` and `id` from a csv. `id` is the artist name and just happens to be the header for that column.

Comment: @DavidNeudorfer: DictReader provides strings.  You can't use %i or %d, you must either convert (using `int`) or use `%s` in the format part of the string.